# Integrar CSS en HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo un HTML que pretendo enviar por correo. debido a ello, no puedo poner rutas relativas a los CSS ¿Hay maneras de integrar el CSS en el código de HTML, es decir, tener todo en un mismo fichero, sin necesidad de incluir los CSS aparte?
(He probado la librería de https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles
pero no me ha funcionado)

He hecho también lo que se sugería en esta respuesta pero tampoco me ha resultado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177881/how-can-i-put-css-and-html-code-in-the-same-file

Comment: Hola User. Puedes explicar mejor tus problemas concretos. DIces que no ha resultado, qué fallos obtuviste?  Cual es el resultado esperado ?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. un saludo

Comment: No obtuve fallos como tal, sino que los estilos no se aplicaban (es decir, al intentar integrar la parte de CSS en el .php como se dice en la pregunta de StackOverflow que he añadido, en lugar de verse el HTML como si tuviera los estilos de css referenciados, se veía sin estilos, es decir, que ignoraba esa parte)

Comment: podrias poner tu codigo que deseas enviar para ayudarte..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitivamente la mejor solución para este problema es utilizar las etiquetas `<style></style>` dentro del `<body>`, ahora que si los estilos no son muchos puedes hacerlo directamente en las etiquetas html `<h1 style="color: blue;">Hola</h1>`

Espero te sirva la respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ponerlo interno

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color: powderblue;}
h1   {color: blue;}
p    {color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

o usar los atributos style de html

```
 <h1 style="color:blue;">This is a Blue Heading</h1>
```

[Fuente](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)

Comment: Esto es lo que se sugiere en la pregunta que he comentado. Me funciona si lo abro normal por el navegador, pero no al enviar el html por mail

Comment: La segunda opcion funciona por mail seguro. Probado ahora mismo.

Comment: La segunda opción debería funcionar sin problemas (al menos es como lo he hecho siempre que he tenido que generar un email en html). Si no te funciona, deberías incluir algo más de información: ¿cómo envías el email? ¿da fallo en todos los gestores de correo o sólo en algunos?

Comment: Lo estoy enviando mediante PHPMailer. Al enviarlo como cuerpo del mensaje no muestra los estilos, pero si le das click a un enlace en ese mismo mail que te redirige a ese mismo HTML pero de manera externa al gestor de correo, funciona bien. Por ahora solo he utilizado gmail.

Comment: Pon el código del envio por favor.

Answer (score 0):

la etiqueta `< style >` la suprimen muchos gestores de correo, si es un email no te queda otra que poner los estilos en linea.

Answer (score 0):

En las cabeceras probablemente tienes **Content-type: text/plain;**

Revisa este ejemplo:

```
<?php 
    $body = "<html>\n"; 
    $body .= "<body style=\"font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; \">\n"; 
    $body = $message; 
    $body .= "</body>\n"; 
    $body .= "</html>\n"; 

    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

    return mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers); 
?>
```

Y asegurarte que **HTML** esta activo en **$mail**:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```